# Badge info/wiki page request

Tags: feature-request, badges

Can we have a "info" wiki page for the given badge the way tags do?

Most of the times the badge is self explaining, but I think it would be interesting to have a wiki-page where examples, rationale, and other interesting texts could be added, just like tags have today.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you might write in one of these wikis?

Comment: Oscar ... though not exactly what you asked for I just added a "Tag Editor" badge for your first tag wiki edit

Answer (score 2):

Check out this question:

What is each badge?

> [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we need that much information about badges, e.g. what good would it do to have a list of examples? Or if people care about the rationale behind the badge (and can't figure it out themselves) they can always ask here on meta.

Sure, some of the current badge descriptions could stand to be improved, but I don't see how a whole info page would be justified.