# Full Badge Descriptions On the Badge Page

Tags: feature-request, badges, hyperlinks

Could we get a link to this **information** (not necessarily the Meta page itself):

[List Of All Badges With Full Descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

On this page:

[Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges)

I love the full descriptions (very informative) but I had to go to Meta and search for it to find it.  It's such a good resource, it seems odd not to have it linked on the Badges page.

Comment: That's exactly what the Meta sites are for no?

Comment: Well, yes, to get the descriptions...  But if the data is readily available, why not offer it to the user?

Comment: Agreed...a link back to the meta site makes sense to me. +1

Comment: For the same reason that the meta sites exist - to discuss the workings of the site.  Each badge has its own (basic) description but if you want more detail you come to the meta site and ask...and then you get linked to the correct page :) Which you have found already :)

Comment: I agree that the meta site is for discussing the workings of the site... hence the question.  =)  We have a page **dedicated** to providing data about badges, and we have a huge list of all badges and their descriptions.  It just screams unity to me...

Comment: +1, maybe keep the short descriptions on the main Badges list, and the clicking on a badge (which brings you to that badge's individual page) shows the full description?

Comment: @jadarnel27 Ohh yeah that's a good idea.

Comment: Not to say the description is sometimes very obscure...

Comment: See also [Make each Badge page a wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81406/make-each-badge-page-a-wiki), [Why is the description on the badges page so sparse?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97071/why-is-the-description-on-the-badges-page-so-sparse) and [Badge info/wiki page request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/badge-info-wiki-page-request).

Answer (score 6):

That would be too much information on the main badges page.

I preffer to make the badge descriptions the same like tag wikis: it will have *excerpt* and *full description* - the badges page will show the excerpt that will be same as the current descriptions, and each badge can have its own full description that will be displayed in that badge page.

For example, instead of this "dry" view:

[image: dry badge view]

It will be:

[image: badge full view]

Comment: Yes, this is what jadarnel27 suggests above, and I really like it.

Comment: @C.Barlow I thought of that before reading the comments on your question, glad you like it. :)

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Great minds think alike =)

Comment: @jadarnel27 yes indeed! :D